# Как сделать анимацию текста, при его появлении на экране?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, html5

Раньше создавал анимацию просто добавлением класса, но сейчас я имею 37 элементов(анимация букв) и сделать это с каждой я считаю невозможно. Как мне сделать так, чтобы только при появлении элемента на экране начиналась анимация?

```css
.animate span {
  display: inline-block;
}
.animate span:nth-of-type(1) {
  animation-delay: .01s;
}
.animate span:nth-of-type(2) {
  animation-delay: .05s;
}
.animate span:nth-of-type(3) {
  animation-delay: .1s;
}
.animate span:nth-of-type(4) {
  animation-delay: .15s;
}
.animate span:nth-of-type(5) {
  animation-delay: .2s;
}
.animate span:nth-of-type(6) {
  animation-delay: .25s;
}
.animate span:nth-of-type(7) {
  animation-delay: .3s;
}
.animate span:nth-of-type(8) {
  animation-delay: .35s;
}
.animate span:nth-of-type(9) {
  animation-delay: .4s;
}
.animate span:nth-of-type(10) {
  animation-delay: .45s;
}
.animate span:nth-of-type(11) {
  animation-delay: .5s;
}
.animate span:nth-of-type(12) {
  animation-delay: .55s;
}
.animate span:nth-of-type(13) {
  animation-delay: .6s;
}
.animate span:nth-of-type(14) {
  animation-delay: .65s;
}
.animate span:nth-of-type(15) {
  animation-delay: .7s;
}
.animate span:nth-of-type(16) {
  animation-delay: .75s;
}
.animate span:nth-of-type(17) {
  animation-delay: .8s;
}
.animate span:nth-of-type(18) {
  animation-delay: .85s;
}
.animate span:nth-of-type(19) {
  animation-delay: .9s;
}
.animate span:nth-of-type(20) {
  animation-delay: .95s;
}
.animate span:nth-of-type(21) {
  animation-delay: 1s;
}
.animate span:nth-of-type(22) {
  animation-delay: 1.05s;
}
.animate span:nth-of-type(23) {
  animation-delay: 1.1s;
}
.animate span:nth-of-type(24) {
  animation-delay: 1.15s;
}
.animate span:nth-of-type(25) {
  animation-delay: 1.2s;
}
.animate span:nth-of-type(26) {
  animation-delay: 1.25s;
}
.animate span:nth-of-type(27) {
  animation-delay: 1.3s;
}
.animate span:nth-of-type(28) {
  animation-delay: 1.35s;
}
.animate span:nth-of-type(29) {
  animation-delay: 1.4s;
}
.animate span:nth-of-type(30) {
  animation-delay: 1.45s;
}
.animate span:nth-of-type(31) {
  animation-delay: 1.5s;
}
.animate span:nth-of-type(32) {
  animation-delay: 1.55s;
}
.animate span:nth-of-type(33) {
  animation-delay: 1.6s;
}
.animate span:nth-of-type(34) {
  animation-delay: 1.65s;
}
.animate span:nth-of-type(35) {
  animation-delay: 1.7s;
}
.animate span:nth-of-type(36) {
  animation-delay: 1.75s;
}
.animate span:nth-of-type(37) {
  animation-delay: 1.8s;
}
.six span {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: rotate(-70deg) translate(65px, 0);
  animation: text-animation .5s forwards;
}


@keyframes text-animation {
  10% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg) translate(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="animate six">
                            <span>М</span><span>ы</span>&nbsp;<span>д</span><span>е</span><span>л</span><span>а</span><span>е</span><span>м</span> &nbsp; <span>в</span><span>а</span><span>ш</span><span>у</span>&nbsp;<span>р</span><span>а</span><span>б</span><span>о</span><span>т</span><span>у</span>&nbsp;<span>б</span><span>ы</span><span>с</span><span>т</span><span>р</span><span>е</span><span>е</span>&nbsp;<span>и</span>&nbsp;  <span>э</span><span>ф</span><span>ф</span><span>е</span><span>к</span><span>т</span><span>и</span><span>в</span><span>н</span><span>е</span><span>е</span>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно добавить js обернуть в функцию и вызвать когда нужно..

```js
function go(str) {
  let cont = document.querySelector('.animate');
  let i = 0, delay = 100;

  for (var j = 0; j < str.length; j++) cont.innerHTML += (str[j] == ' ') ? '&nbsp;' : '<span>'+str[j]+'</span>';

  let span = document.querySelectorAll('.animate > span');

  let interval = setInterval(() => {
    if (i == span.length) return clearInterval(interval);
    span[i].setAttribute('class', 'anim');
    i++;
  }, delay);
}

go('Мы делаем вашу работу быстрее и эффективнее')
```

```css
.animate span {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotate(-70deg) translate(65px, 0);
}

.anim {
  animation: text-animation .5s forwards;
}

@keyframes text-animation {
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg) translate(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="animate"></div>
```